# Run query on each DB and display DB Name too

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

using samples I found in this site, I succedeed to write the following query.
It works well, however, I would like to get the name of each database being queried be reported in the results, next to those 2 columns. All my attempts have failed. Any help, please.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

SELECT @sql = Coalesce(@sql + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 'SELECT column1, column2 FROM ' + QuoteName(name) + '.dbo.T_MyTable'
FROM   sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 AND state = 0
;

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql);
```

as an example, the following fails with an Invalid column name error

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

SELECT @sql = Coalesce(@sql + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 'SELECT SoStoreNameTx, SoStoreNoTx, ' + quotename(name) + ' FROM ' + QuoteName(name) + '.dbo.T_SoStore'
FROM   sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 AND state = 0
;

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: Did you try adding Quotename(name) to column list after column2? (before FROM keyword). It should be embraced with '' so you just select a string.

Comment: Thank you, I have and it failed. I edit my question to add the failing query

Comment: @DeepDiver look at the PRINT - you are selecting the database name without containing it in single quotes - The answer below shows you how you should do it.

Comment: See my answer. In your query SQL Server thinks that the quoted name is a name of the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below

```
   DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

    SELECT @sql = Coalesce(@sql + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 'SELECT column1, column2, ''' + QuoteName(name)+  ''' as DBname FROM ' + QuoteName(name) + '.dbo.T_MyTable'
    FROM   sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 AND state = 0
    ;

    PRINT @sql
    EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: That works perfectly, really appreciated. It will also help me patch another similar query.